# What is the bootsqm.dat file and is it safe to delete it?

Tags: windows

I see a file called `bootsqm.dat` in the root of my `C:\` and `D:\` drives. What is this file and is it safe to delete it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This file is created after the **chkdsk** tool completes. It is safe to delete it.